# Exponential inequality in proof

Tags: inequality, exponential-function, self-learning

I'm reading Wainwright's [High Dimensional Statistics](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/highdimensional-statistics/8A91ECEEC38F46DAB53E9FF8757C7A4E) and am currently trying to wrap my head around the proof of Proposition 2.14. At some point, the author states:

$$
e^{-\lambda \mathbb{E}[X]} \cdot \left(1 + \lambda \mathbb{E}[X] + \frac{1}{2}
\lambda^2 \mathbb{E}[X^2] h(\lambda b) \right) \leq
\exp\left(\frac{\lambda^2 \mathbb{E}[X^2]}{2} h(\lambda b)\right)
$$
where $X$ is a random variable almost surely bounded above by $b$ and $h(u) := 2 \frac{e^u -u - 1}{u^2}$, and $\lambda > 0$.
**Where is this inequality coming from?** It's easy to verify it is true when $\mathbb{E}[X] \geq 0$, but there is
no such assumption in the proposition.

Full context:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Where is the inequality?

Comment: @angryavian: I'm so sorry, I don't know how I managed to screw it up. It's been added now.

Comment: @VHarisop  It is just $\mathrm{e}^x \ge 1 + x$.